# get a substring using regex

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas. I am trying to fetch a multiple substring from a string. But I need to check between particular start and end.

if it is present i need to get its position, which substring.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
target = 'hi|love'

m = df['sequence'].str.contains(target)

df.loc[m, 'output'] = (df.loc[m, 'sequence']
                         .str.replace(fr'.*({target}).*',
                                      lambda m: f'{m.start(1)+1},{m.group(1)}',
                                      regex=True)
                       )

df.loc[~m, 'output'] = 'NA'
```

Output:

```
      sequence  output
0   HelloWorld      NO
1    worldofhi    8,hi
2  worldoflove  8,love
```

Used input:

```
      sequence
0   HelloWorld
1    worldofhi
2  worldoflove
```

##### checking only in substring 7:10

```
target = 'hi|love'

s = df['sequence'].str[7:10+1]

m = s.str.contains(target)

df.loc[m, 'output'] = (s[m]
                         .str.replace(fr'.*({target}).*',
                                      lambda m: f'{m.start(1)+7+1},{m.group(1)}',
                                      regex=True)
                       )

df.loc[~m, 'output'] = 'NA'
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need the string to be checked only from 7 to 10 in the position.

Comment: @julie then, just slice before and add 7 to the position, see update

Comment: Thank you so much. But may I know what is actually doing here `s[m]
                         .str.replace(fr'.*({target})',
                                      lambda m: f'{m.start(1)+7+1},{m.group(1)}',`

Comment: When there is another sequence like    "worldofhide" , the output print like "hid" instead of "hi"

Comment: Do you wan to match the end of string? What you expect is unclear, please be specific.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, for example, consider I have another input sequence "worldofhide". According to my explanation, the output should be "8,hi". But now it will be printing like "8,hid". It will print an extra "d".

Comment: Another example is like let's say the input sequence is "worldihide". The output should be like "7,hi". But the above program is giving output as "7,hide".

Comment: @julie OK, see update I added a `.*` to remove the end of string as well